# Spring send different response

Tags: java, spring, rest, model-view-controller

How can I sent the different answers, if I have different errors using Spring Frameworks?

```
@RestController
public class MainController{

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public Object login(){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Exception Handling

```
@RequestMapping(value = "login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public LoginResponse login(@RequestBody SignInRequest request) throws EmailNotValidException {
    if (isValidEmailAddress(request.getEmail())) throw new EmailNotValidException();

    return response;
}
```

after this, you can write method with @ExceptionHandler annotation

```
    @ExceptionHandler({EmailNotValidException.class,DataAccessException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<BaseResponse> dummyExceptionHandler() {
         return new ResponseEntity<>(new BaseResponse("error"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

Comment: Your welcome.
You can find more here: 
https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Comment: What is the BaseResponse class?

Comment: It's your created class, you can change it for whatever you want, like String, Integer or your BaseResponse.

Comment: Nice, thank you again!